# I can't use ufw on Ubuntu 20.04: "command not found"

Tags: 20.04, ufw

Somehow, I can't use `sudo ufw`. The terminal keeps saying:

```
command not found
```

Comment: Maybe you have not installed it yet?

Answer (score 26):

Is it even installed on your system?

You can install UFW with

```
sudo apt install ufw
```

You can get help with UFw with

```
ufw --help
```

You can download UFW directly from the ubuntu software center:

[image]

But, above all else, you can set paramenters for UFW using the GUI by installing Firewall Configuration tool from the ubuntu software center.

[image]

[reference](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/1330/how-to-secure-your-linux-server-with-a-ufw-firewall/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the package is installed, it may not be included in the PATH.

You can find the binary location by looking at the list of files installed by running: `dpkg -L ufw`

If your platform doesn't have that then you can brute-force search for the binary with this command: `sudo find / -name ufw`

You should find it in one of the bin or sbin folders, then run `echo "$PATH"` and check if the ufw binary folder is included.

If the folder is not included you'll need to add it to your PATH either temporarily by using this command `export PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"` (replacing /usr/sbin with your ufw folder), or permanently by adding this to .profile or .bashrc (wherever your config is) `PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"`